# Response status code showing 200 for gateway error (504)

Tags: java, http-status-code-504

I have a REST endpoint which call another API which take a while to process and returning 504 error when I verify through Rest client (Insomnia). But in my service I see this transaction as success 200 not 504.

Below is how my code snippet:

```
public ResponseEntity<Customer> processResponse(Customer customer, String restUri) {

    ResponseEntity<Customer> response;
    String customerJson = null;
    try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization(userName, password).build();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<Customer> entity = new HttpEntity<>(customer, headers);
        CustomerJson = jacksonUtil.toJSON(customer);
        response = restTemplate.exchange(restUri, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, Customer.class);

        if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            logger.info("Return success from the server");
        } else {
            logger.error("Error while getting the response from the server");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    }
    return response;
}
```

What am I missing here? Why its not executing the else block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems to be returning null response in case of error. Can you check if you have done any handling in caller and passing 200 from controller layer itself.